# Sailjs/Waterline - Is there any way to get previously fetched objects?

Tags: model, sails.js, waterline

I believe that I saw somebody wrote about a way to fetch the in-memory objects from a model object to reduce DB access. Could some body please advise or share me the document?

I would like to have something like this:

```
ModelA.create({...}).populate('modelBs').exec(function(err, instanceA) {
    // Do some nested things here, for example:
    instanceA.prop1 = someNewValue;
    instanceA.save(function(err, instanceAModified) {
       // I want to call some method from instanceAModified, to get all 'modelB' objects here, without accessing the DB once more.
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that in the newest release of Waterline, `.save()` will re-populate any associations in its callback.  But regardless, you can always hang on to them by saving them in a local variable.  Assuming you meant `find` and not `create` above (since `populate` doesn't do anything on `create`):

```
ModelA.find({...}).populate('modelBs').exec(function(err, instanceA) {
    // Do some nested things here, for example:
    instanceA.prop1 = someNewValue;
    var modelBs = instanceA.modelBs;
    instanceA.save(function(err, instanceAModified) {
       // modelBs will still be available here.
    });
});
```